# How to active UserControl outside the wrapper?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I met a `Focus` related problem in `UserControl`:

Suppose we have a UserControl like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="_20130826.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="text1" />
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="text2" />
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="text3" />
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="text4" />
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And the `MainWindow.xaml` like this:

```
<Window x:Class="_20130826.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:temp="clr-namespace:_20130826"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Deactive UserControl" />
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Name="Button1" Content="Active UserControl" />
            <ContentControl>
                <temp:UserControl1 />
            </ContentControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

- Step 1: Click `text1` TextBlock inside `UserControl`, and default the
  background changes to **deeper**.
- Step 2: Click '`Deactive UserControl`' button, so the text1 background
  turns to **lighter**.
- Step 3: Click '`Active UserControl`' button, then ...

I want the `text1` background changed to **deeper**, **which means the UserControl has been focused/actived**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure if i follow this right but your `Button`("Active UserControl") is not actually within your `UserControl`, so why do you expect the userControl to get focus when the Button is pressed? right now both Buttons only belong to the `MainWindow`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Thanks @Viv, actually the complete scenario like this: We have a user control inside a ToolWindow, we want to active the user control when user actives ToolWindow, for now the user control has not effects if user did that.

Comment: Ok so you want the `UserControl` to get focus when the "Active UserControl" button gets pressed?

Comment: @Viv, yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the Focus to the `UserControl` when the `Button`("Active UserControl") gets pressed, we can add a Click event handler and assign focus to the UserControl.

So say something like:

```
<Window x:Class="_20130826.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:temp="clr-namespace:_20130826"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Deactive UserControl" />
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Name="Button1" Content="Active UserControl" Click="Button1_OnClick" />
            <ContentControl>
                <temp:UserControl1 x:Name="myUserControl" />
            </ContentControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```cs
private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, myUserControl);
}
```

Now when you click the "Active UserControl" `Button`, Focus will switch to the `UserControl`. However this will not give you that "deeper" state on the `ListBoxItem` as it still doesnt have Focus. So to sort that

In `UserControl1.xaml.cs` add:

```cs
protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e) {
  base.OnGotFocus(e);

  if (!Equals(e.OriginalSource, this))
    return;
  TraversalRequest tRequest = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
  MoveFocus(tRequest);
}
```

What this does is when the `UserControl` gets focus, it moves Focus to the next element within it which would be the element you clicked initially.

You can get a demo of your code tweaked with this: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/89iol1pg74i0dsd/FocusUC.rar)